# Context separation for a group of entities

Tags: domain-driven-design

We currently handle a well separated monolithic service which handles various 'contexts' to help with the separation. I haven't had any issues so far when dealing with problems that require the creation of a new context since it was simple enough.

Now I'm dealing with a group of entities (3, to be exact) that relate to each other and I'm not sure how to properly organize one of them in the project.

For the example we'll name them Branch, BranchService, Service.

Branch lives in its own context as does Service, but at the moment I am not sure where to place BranchService. In this case, BranchService is not just an entity to handle many-to-many, it has some information on it's own that is used around the service.

Since they are relatively coupled, should they be together and share the same context? Or is there an alternative for this case?

Comment: Ruby on Rails calls this concept a "Many to Many through..." relationship.  The concept was to distinguish the fact that the relationship was it's own entity, but it still handled that many-to-many function.  So for organization purposes, I might recommend treating it like a Many to Many and for application purposes treat it like it's own entity.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this depends on business-specific context that helps in understanding how these relate to one another.

For example, you'll find the same three entities in a basic video rental store example: `Customer`, `Video` and `Rental`, where `Rental` contains a FK to both `Customer` and `Video` and some other rental-specific data.

I have nothing to go on other than the very vague names you've used for your entities, so any answer I can give is merely an interpretation of what the context *seems to be*.

Given the existence of `BranchService`-specific data, this suggests to me that this entity has a purpose other than acting as the cross product of its two referenced entities. But in fairness, I would then also expect that it has its own independent name, not a name that is merely the concatenation of its two referenced entities.

This is where that contextual knowledge would help in distinguishing the purpose of the entity. As I see it, there are three main options here:

**1**
If there is individual purpose to this entity, it should exist on its own. Merely referencing another entity is not enough to argue that it is a subentity belonging to that parent entity.

Using the video rental example; if there is an entire subset of the application dedicated to rentals (e.g. profit reporting is a good example here as it wholly depends on the rentals themselves), then rentals clearly have an independent purpose and should therefore exist in their own context.

**2**
If there is no individual purpose to this entity, and your business context presents the `BranchService` as contextually "belonging to" one entity (e.g. `Branch`), then it makes sense to keep this within the `Branch` context and implement it as a sub-aggregate to the `Branch` aggregate root. The same goes for `Service` of course, if the `BranchService` contextually appears to "belong to" `Service`.

Using the video rental example, it may be the case that rentals are only ever viewed as part of a customer, and that there is no reasonable use case to ever view the opposite (i.e. viewing a video and all of its rentals). In such a case, the rentals can be considered to be a sub-aggregate of the customer, even if they implement a many-to-many on a database level. This encapsulates rentals to be a part of the customer and hides it from all other contexts (such as the video context).

**3**
If there is no individual purpose to this entity, and your business context does not present the `BranchService` as contextually "belonging to" one entity (e.g. because they all claim contextual ownership at one point or another), then it clearly must exist in its own context and should exist on its own.

Using the video rental example, if you both need to present views for a customer with all their rentals *and* a video and all of its rentals; then there is no clear singular owner of the rentals.. In such a case, the rentals should exist on their own, so that any and all interested parties have equal standing to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by Context you mean these are vertical entities and they are logically separated (by assembly boundary or a dependency checker)?

With the limited information I have, can the services be layered? Can BranchService be a parent of Branch and Service and have a domain that concerns the relationships between the two?

Like, you are managing auto repair stores which have different kinds of oil change machines. So you model the stores and the oil change machines and they have their own operations and are directly accessible. You also have a service locator service with reference to the oil change machine service and stores services which can do tasks like finding the nearest location where we can fit another size large oil change machine.